# Duplicated entries in referenced array - MongoDB - Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to MongoDb and I met this problem days ago and I can't resolve it. Basically, my user is allowed to create new Post with a bunch of Images. When I create the Post, then I create also the Images but when I check on mongo shell the entries in the array of the Post, one image can be present two or three times. (All the images are saved with an url)

These are my Models:

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   Name: String,
   Background: String,
   Description: String,
   posted: {type:Date,default: Date.now() },
   images: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "image"}]
});

var imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    src: String,
    caption: String
});
```

(These Schema are in separeted files and then exported as model)

This is my code for saving Post:

```
app.post("/post",isLoggedIn,function(req,res){

   var post= {Name: req.body.name, 
              Background: req.body.backg,
              Description: req.body.desc};

   Posts.create(post, function(err, newPost){
      if(err){
         console.log(err);
      } else {
            var allImages = req.body.img;
            allImages.forEach(function(singleImg){
            Images.create(singleImg, function(err, newImg){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                   newPost.images.push(newImg);
                   newPost.save(function(err){
                     if(err){
                       return res.send(err);
                    }
                 });
               }
           });
        });
      }
   });
   return res.redirect("/posts");
});
```

**Edit** 
This is my code with **$addToSet**

```
app.post("/post",isLoggedIn,function(req,res){

       var post= {Name: req.body.name, 
                  Background: req.body.backg,
                  Description: req.body.desc};

       Posts.create(post, function(err, newPost){
          if(err){
             console.log(err);
          } else {
             Posts.findByIdAndUpdate(newPost._id, {$addToSet:{images: {$each: req.body.img}}}, function(err, updatedPost){
                 return res.redirect("/posts");
            });
          }
       });
    });
```

It gives me **CastError Cast to ObjectId failed**

Comment: There is nothing that actually stops that happening if using `$push` or the `model.push()` operations. If you need to keep them unique, then make sure to use [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

Comment: I'll try to use $addToSet

Comment: Show your code in the question.

Comment: Yeah, now I edit

Answer (score 0):

**Don't forget hanlde errors**

Edit your code: (**With Mongoose + nodejs - I suggest use indexOf, It runs very well with me, My DB have about 10M records**)

**From**

```
Posts.create(post, function(err, newPost){
      if(err){
         console.log(err);
      } else {
            var allImages = req.body.img;
            allImages.forEach(function(singleImg){
            Images.create(singleImg, function(err, newImg){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                   newPost.images.push(newImg);
                   newPost.save(function(err){
                     if(err){
                       return res.send(err);
                    }
                 });
               }
           });
        });
      }
   });
```

**to**

```
Posts.create(post, function(err, newPost){
      if(err){
         console.log(err);
      } else {
            var allImages = req.body.img;
            allImages.forEach(function(singleImg){
            Images.create(singleImg, function(err, newImg){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    // Check exist
                    if (newPost.images.indexOf(newImg._id) == -1) {
                        newPost.images.push(newImg._id);
                        newPost.save(function(err){
                            if(err) {
                               return res.send(err);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log(newImg);
                        // do something
                    }
               }
           });
        });
      }
   });
```

OR

Use $addToSet if you use MongoDb or Mongoose

Hope it will help you.

Thank you

Comment: I tried your first solution and it keeps duplicating images

Comment: It is ok? my friend @Marsquale

Comment: Send msg if you fix it done :) This code is run very well with me

Comment: Are you sure ? I'm getting crazy ahaha. Did you use the exactly same code you paste here ? Thank you anyway!